# VC++2005: Automating the build for 32 AND 64 Bit

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I'm using MS Visual C++ and have to deliver a 32 and 64 bit version of the same project in one installer. That's error-prone of course, I might forget to update one, so I want to automate the build process. But the "dependencies" work only between different projects.

Is there a way to have one build trigger (e.g. of the 32 bit version) a second one (e.g. the 64 bit version and as post-build step the installer)?

Thanks!

Comment: wouldn't it be better to have too separate projects and use the Batch Build command?

Answer (score 0):

It's considered to be bad practice to build deliveries from within an IDE. Rather, consider using a [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) server. This way, after writing a build script, you'll never forget to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a command line build using a batch file to trigger both builds using a command line invocation of devenv.exe as part of the installer build?

Comment: Not perfect, but works after some tweaking. Thanks for the idea!